# Rails - Routing Error 'No route matches [PUT]'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to make a small app that allows users to create a sale. There is a user model product model and photo model. A user has many products and products has many photos. But for some reason after I try to create a product page I get this error.

**Routing Error**

```
No route matches [PUT] "/products"
```

**routes.rb**

```
  resources :products
  resources :photos
```

**products controller**

```
  def new 
    @product = Product.new
    @photo = Photo.new
  end

  def create
    @product = current_user.products.build(params[:product])
    @photo = current_user.photos.new(params[:photo])

    if @product.save && @photo.save
      @photo.product_id = @product.id
      render "show", :notice => "Sale created!"
    else
      render "new", :notice => "Somehting went wrong!"
    end
  end

  def show
    @product = Product.find(params[:id]) 
  end
```

**new product page (HAML)**

```
%h1 
  create item

= form_for @product,:url => products_path, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f|          
  %p
    = f.label :name
    = f.text_field :name

  %p
    = f.label :description
    = f.text_field :description        
    = f.text_field :ship_price

  %p
    = fields_for :photo, :html => {:multipart => true} do |fp|
    = fp.file_field :image  

  %p.button
    = f.submit
```

**rake routes**

```
       products GET    /products(.:format)               products#index
                POST   /products(.:format)               products#create
    new_product GET    /products/new(.:format)           products#new
   edit_product GET    /products/:id/edit(.:format)      products#edit
        product GET    /products/:id(.:format)           products#show
                PUT    /products/:id(.:format)           products#update
                DELETE /products/:id(.:format)           products#destroy
```

Shouldn't this work if I already did resources:products !?

Comment: Try not to pass :url into form_for.

Comment: Are you sure there is no other code we're not seeing here? Rails will make the form a put method if the object is [persisted](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-persisted-3F)

Comment: ^ hey matt what code should i link? Users controller?

Comment: @AlainGoldman Any before filters in the product controller, any code that acts on the `@product` object in the view or controller, or anything that might be acting on it from a helper.

Comment: yes the product controller has   before_filter :require_login
 before_filter :current_user, only: [:create, :destory]
 before_filter :correct_user, only: :destory

Comment: @AlainGoldman Just a thought, is this error happening on the first submit of the form after going to `/new` or is it happening on the second submit after a validation failure?

Comment: i'm not sure what that means exactly but I get the error on http://localhost:3000/products after submission and it doesnt add to db

Comment: What I mean is, when you go to the new action for the first time, and submit the form, does it show a validation error `"Somehting went wrong!"` and allow you to submit the form again?

Comment: yes it does that exactly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple of problems here. Firstly your @photo object isn't saving, which is causing your view to render the `new` action for the successfully saved @product (thus making the form with a `put` method since the object is `persisted?`). It may be because you are setting the photo's product_id *after* the save instead of before:

```
  if @product.save && @photo.save
    @photo.product_id = @product.id
```

Try adding the id before the save, see if both objects are then valid.

You still have a bit of a logic problem in that you're redirecting to `new` if either of the objects fails to save. Instead of doing this, check if both of the objects are valid, then save them if so or redirect if not! Then when redirected to `new` the object hasn't been saved and the form will be created as a proper `post` form:

```
def create
  @product = current_user.products.build(params[:product])
  @photo = current_user.photos.new(params[:photo])
  @photo.product_id = @product.id 

  if @product.valid? && @photo.valid?
    @product.save
    @photo.save
    render "show", :notice => "Sale created!"
  else
    render "new", :notice => "Something went wrong!" # the product object hasn't been saved, this is now the correct form type
  end
end
```

Lastly, add the error messages for the object(s) to your new page so you can tell what is invalid.

```
<% if @product.errors.any? %>
  <%= pluralize(@product.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this product from being saved:

  <ul>
    <% @product.errors.full_messages.each do |error_message| %>
      <li><%= error_message %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your products controller doesn't contain an edit and update method. PUT is for update.

Comment: that was not the full product controller. it was shortened for clarity.

Comment: It isn't the problem. The problem is that creation form is generated with PUT method instead of POST.

Answer (score -1):

Check your routes(rake routes) maybe your put routes is not correct and you dont create in your controllers the :

```
def destroy 

end
```

Comment: what does that have to do with anything. I tried it and it does not work.

Comment: Hum the problem is when you call your form , rails think you wants delete it ( reason need routes PUT ) can you display  the rake routes please ? Maybe use product_path and not products_path

Comment: Okay i just added the rake routes to the original post

Comment: Change products_path to product_path